# How to count the number of data with specific conditions from columns using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a data file of following format

```
AA 21.1218 14.7862 0.0566269
BB 26.5036 14.5513 19.975
CC 7.82448 1.30605 50.126899
AA 10.0179 4.3786 21.232036
BB 4.80236 4.23255 36.217038
CC 31.475 9.60365 7.237505
AA 8.39392 5.89571 10.30242
......
```

Here, I want to do is

check the 1st & 4th column, count the number of data which have the number greater than 12 in 4th column, and 'BB' in the first column, (in above example, it should be 2), then multiply 20 to that number. (Final answer should be 40)

I was beginning from

```
awk '{print ($4>12)}' file > file2
wc -l file2
```

to check the 4th column's number, and print the line number.

But obviously they didn't worked. It seems awk cannot use < or > operator inside. (greater than or less than) How can I achieve this oeration with cat, awk, sed, or grep?

Thanks

Comment: @Ed Morton I was meaning "greater than" or "less than"

Comment: @ Ed Morton But I can only see 0 and 1 in the file2... Maybe my approach was wrong...

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. I'm reading again the manual for the awk

Comment: To really learn awk get the book Effective Awk Programing, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'm logging in the amazon. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print matching lines:

```
awk '$1 == "BB" && $4 > 12' file
```

(the implicit action `{print}` is performed)

You can also do the counting and the multiplication:

```
awk 'BEGIN {count = 0} $1 == "BB" && $4 > 12 {count++} END {print(count * 20)}' file
```

Comment: Thanks. This is quite simple but perfect. If I use the awk if statement, would it be faster than your method?

Comment: @exsonic01 you mean like `awk '{if ($1 == "BB" && $4 > 12) print}'` ? I don't think there will be any difference, but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, Sometimes my file is very huge, so I was just curious which one would be faster, but I can test by myself. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to init numeric awk variables to zero so you don't need that `BEGIN` section at all. You also don't need the parens around the expression that `print` is printing.

Comment: @EdMorton you are right about both. But I believe having explicit init block better illustrates what's going on. And about parens - I just like them, I think expression looks better that way :)

Comment: IMHO down that path lies the demon of specifying other things that don't need to be explicitly written like `FS=" "` and `RS="\n"`, etc but if it works for you....

Answer (score 0):

The same approach without needing an extra counter variable :

```
awk '{ +$4 <= 12 || FNR -= $1 == "BB" } END { print 20 * (NR - FNR) } '
```